# How can get Set-Cookies from 404 Http Error in Angular?

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, rxjs, response

Hello guys I want login to website.

I post formData with valid email and password on this Url https://www.imo.net/members/imo_registration/login/ and response return 404 error and this all "right" (I dont make this server but if i valid login on this server. Server return 404 with page. More in images).

As you can see i valid login this page but i want from this response get Set-Cookie. How can i do it?

Login event onClick button:

```
async onLogin(id: number) {
    await this.componentsUtils.loadingShow();

    this.imoService.login().pipe(
      tap((data: any) => {
        // not print
        console.log("data", data);
      }),
      finalize(() => this.componentsUtils.loadingHide()),
    ).subscribe(
      res => {
        // not print
        console.log('HTTP res', res);
      },
      err => {
        // here i catch error
        console.log('HTTP Error', err)
      },
    );
 }
```

ImoService:

```
export class ImoService {

  private resourceUrl: string = "https://www.imo.net";

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  login(email: string = "someEmail@gmail.com", password: string = "somePassword"): Observable<any> {
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('password', password);

    return this.http.post<any>(this.resourceUrl + "/members/imo_registration/login/", formData);
  }
}
```

Console log: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHb2l.png)

Network: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaa2w.png)

Page after valid login: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Tbl.png)

Comment: it kind of depends on the cookie and the domain your site is operating on. if this is a cross origin request, then you can't see the cookies. if the cookie is http only, then you can't see the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an additional argument to the httpClient when you are making the request.

```
return this.http.post<any>(this.resourceUrl + "/members/imo_registration/login/", formData, {observe: 'response'});
```

Be careful that the method now returns an HttpResponse object containing all the response from the server and not just the body.

You can access the 'Set-Cookie' header like this

```
resp.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
```

and you can access the response's body with

```
resp.body
```